# ServiceStack : Serialize long number to string

Tags: servicestack-text

In my C# code, I have a `long` variable like

```
public long ID { get; set; }
```

Now when ServiceStack returns it to Web browser, it is serialized as

```
{ "id" : 97786707294275442 }
```

This is wrong because `long` has a range of **2^63** in C#

But in Javascript, [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) is 2^53-1, which is **9007199254740991**

Because 97786707294275442 is greater than 9007199254740991, the number is rounded in JS.

Is it possible to let ServiceStack serialize `long` to `string` when its value is greater than [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JsConfig<long>.RawSerializeFn = (long num) =>
            {
                if (num > 9007199254740991L || num < -9007199254740991L)
                    return string.Format("\"{0}\"", num);
                return num.ToString();
            };
```

Is it the best way?